# shake - rule finished running but did not produce file:

Tags: shake-build-system

I try to use shake to convert some markdonw files to html ("bake"). The markdown files are in a directory "dough" and the html should go to "baked". The goal is to produce the `index.html` file, which links the other files.

This is my first use of shake!

The conversion works, but at the end the first rule produces the error

```
`rule finished running but did not produce file:`
```

The cause is perhaps that the `index.html` file is produced before (with the second rule). How can I tell the first rule not to expect a result (or force the production again)?

secondary question: how to change the first rule to collect files with extension "md" and "markdown"?

Thank you for the help! Suggestions for improvements are most welcome!

```
bakedD  = "site/baked" -- toFilePath bakedPath
doughD = "site/dough"

shakeWrapped :: IO  ()
shakeWrapped = shakeArgs shakeOptions {shakeFiles=bakedD
                , shakeVerbosity=Loud
                , shakeLint=Just LintBasic
                } $
    do
        want ["index"<.>"html"]

        "index"<.>"html" %> \out ->
            do
                mds <- getDirectoryFiles  doughD ["//*.md"] 
                let htmlFiles = [bakedD </> md -<.> "html" | md <- mds]

                need htmlFiles
                liftIO $  bakeOneFileIO  "baked/index.html"

        (bakedD <> "//*.html") %> \out ->
            do
                let c = dropDirectory1 $ out -<.> "md"
                liftIO $  bakeOneFileIO  c
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message notes that you declare the file to produce `index.html`, but it doesn't produce that file. From a read of your build system, it appears it produces `based/index.html`? If so, change the `want` line area to read:

```
do
    want ["baked/index.html"]

    "baked/index.html" %> \out ->
```

Now you are saying at the end of the execution you want to produce a file `baked/index.html`, and that here is a rule that produces `baked/index.html`. (If it's really producing `site/baked/index.html` then adjust appropriately.)

Addressing your second question, `mds <- getDirectoryFiles  doughD ["//*.md","//*.markdown"]` will detect both extensions.

As for style tips, using `"index" <.> "html"` is not really helping - `"index.html"` is identical but clearer to read. Other than that, it seems pretty idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the first rule wants a file, but this file is included (and produced) by the second rule. There is an indication for that problematic case that the `\out` variable is not used and the production of the `index.htm` is not required in this rule (as it is included in the second rule). One can take this as an indication that a phony rule would be appropriate and simplify the code:

```
bakedD  = "site/baked" -- toFilePath bakedPath
doughD = "site/dough"

shakeWrapped :: IO  ()
shakeWrapped = shakeArgs shakeOptions {shakeFiles=bakedD
                , shakeVerbosity=Loud
                , shakeLint=Just LintBasic
                } $
    do
        want ["allMarkdownConversion"]

        phony "allMarkdownConversion" $  
            do
                mds <- getDirectoryFiles  doughD ["//*.md"] -- markdown ext ??
                let htmlFiles = [bakedD </> md -<.> "html" | md <- mds]
--                liftIO $ putIOwords ["shakeWrapped - htmlFile", showT htmlFiles]
                need htmlFiles

        (bakedD <> "//*.html") %> \out ->
            do
                let c = dropDirectory1 $ out -<.> "md"
                liftIO $  bakeOneFileIO  c
```

I think that shake is a very convenient method to add a cache to a static site generator; it rebuilds only what is required!